# Codeigniter Language Helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I have implement the Multiple Language using the Language Helper.I am loading the helper on drop-down change, means when user select any language then I load library according then.
My problem is that if no language file found then it shows error

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/abc/abc_lang.php
```

I want that if no file found then Simple English select.
So I try this code but getting same error

```
$language = $_POST['language'];

if(($this->lang->load($language,$language)) == 1){
     $this->lang->load($language,$language);
}

else{
    $this->lang->load('english','english');
}
```

Anyone can tell me how to solve it.

Comment: It might be worth just doing a simple `empty($_POST['language'])` check on that value and setting a default value for if 1 as not been set. You could do something like $language = (! empty($_POST['language'])) ? $_POST['language'] : 'default-language';` to make it easier to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message is triggered by your attempt to load a non-existing language file in your conditional statement. I would recommend you checking if the language file exists before trying to load it:

```
if (file_exists(APPPATH."language/".$expectedLanguage."/".$expectedFile)) {
    $this->lang->load($expectedFile, $expectedLanguage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that, how many option you have in drop-down that number of lang file you have to create on languages folder. then it will get its expected lang file as per you change from drop-down and not show error.